# C++ insert in struct

Tags: c++

My code is the following:

```
struct d
{
    char name[5];
};

vector<d> my_d;
my_d.resize(3);

strcpy(my_d[0].name, "mike");
strcpy(my_d[1].name, "joe");

//how to insert "anna" between "mike" and "joe"
my_d.insert(my_d.begin()+1, "anna");//doesn't work???
```

I am trying to insert an element between the elements, as show above. But the compiler refuses to compile, `No instance of overloaded function maches the agreement list.`.

Comment: Why are you using fixed-length `char` arrays and `strcpy`, rather than `std::string`?

Comment: What error do you get from the compiler?

Comment: But the answer to your problem is: `insert` expects you to give it an object of the relevant type.  The relevant type here is `d`.  `"anna"` is not a `d`.

Comment: no instance of overloaded function maches the agreement list.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I see your point, but how to fix this?

Comment: the char[] are used for performance reasons.

Comment: Generally this is the purpose of argumented constructors.

Comment: I hope nobody with a 6 letter name tries to use your code!

Comment: yes, i banned all of those guys -_-

Comment: @JBentley 5 letters would even cause problems, since there won't be the null terminating character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion from a string literal (`const char*`) into a `d` type. You'll have to make the new `d` struct, copy the string into it, then add it to `my_d`:

```
d newItem;
strcpy(newItem.name, "anna");
my_d.insert(my_d.begin()+1, newItem);
```

If you want implicit type conversion, you need to provide a constructor on the `d` struct like this:

```
struct d {
    char name[5];

    d(const char* name_) {
        strcpy(name, name_);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or provide a suitable constructor for `d`.

Comment: It works, but isn't there something more elegant? how to use a constructor on a struct?

Comment: I've added an example of implicit type conversion.

Comment: How to sort the struct based on name, using std::sort?