# Sorting algorithms for unique data

Tags: c++, sorting

What sorting algorithms perform better than quicksort when the data being sorted are:

a) unique
b) in completely random positions
c) large in number (>1m)
d) the data are in memory, in a vector
e) they are character arrays
f) I don't care how much memory the algorithm will use

I understand, this kind of question can have many variables, so I tried to provide as many information I could.

Comment: You have to test different algorithms with your data running in your environment. Other than some broad statements, it's nigh on impossible (and generally, foolhardy) to second guess performance of an algorithm without measurements.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you give 1, 2 or 3 and say: one of those will do it, please?

Comment: Yes - std::sort as provided by the C++ standard library. It probably uses quicksort under the hood. But it will have been written for general purpose performance, tested by someone else, and likely to be good enough. Don't try and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Also, why character arrays and not std::strings?

Comment: for performance reasons.

Comment: is there a way to make something insanely complex using threads?

Comment: I'm going to sound like a broken record, but have you compared the two?

Comment: yes, i have, very small difference, but why not?

Comment: Try this out: http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/467934

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have character arrays and don't care about memory (although, you do are limited by the hardware memory available, so I don't know how you can not care) you can use Radix sort. It has a complexity of O(n). And you can also very easily parallelise this algorithm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578014/c-insert-in-struct <-- How to sort the struct based on name, using std::sort?

Comment: @SkyRipper std::sort won't do a radix sort for you; it does an n log n sort.